# Android stock chart

Tags: android, charts, quote, stock

I want to build a stock chart, but do not know which library I should use.

Can any library build the dynamic chart to be the background of the view？Thank you.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring that out. Did you have a question that doesn't involve off-topic requests to find/recommend libraries for you?

Comment: yes . Any lib can build this chart? I try achartengine  but not perfect~~

Answer (score 2):

It's worth checking out SciChart, which has a very powerful [iOS & Android Stock Chart control](https://www.scichart.com/android-stock-charts).

[image]

It is a commercial component, however it is a very fast and powerful chart library which [beats MPAndroidChart by a very clear margin in performance tests](https://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/). Sorry MPAndroidChart!

You can now clone the [Android Chart examples on Github](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples) and have a play around with the controls and see how we created the above example app!

***Full disclosure*** - I am the tech lead on the SciChart project

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib-https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.I used it for one of my projects.

If the requirements seems to be simple enough you could also try to write your own graph.Its pretty simple to do it in android.

Comment: Thx. And I will try this one.